# Why does "git rm dir/file" delete `dir` as well, when `file` is the only file in `dir`?

Tags: git

Start with an empty directory.

```
git init
mkdir dir
touch dir/file1
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git rm dir/file1
```

`ls` shows that nothing is left. But I'm expecting `dir`, which is the result when `/bin/rm` is used instead of `git rm`. What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because git monitor contents only, and contents can only reside in files.

So empty directory cannot be monitor by git, hence it's deleted.

To keep a directory, one usually create a dummy file it in. Usually the file is named `.gitkeep` or `.gitignore`. You can leave the file empty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's my guess. But how could one find this in git documentation?

Comment: @JoeLi https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial#_git_tracks_content_not_files